# Having trouble displaying thai characters in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, fonts

Hi I am writing a small utility too using silverlight 3 and WCF for our localization team to check and correct the translations stored in .NET resource files (*.resx).

The tool displays all the text from selected resource file in a grid and allows the user to edit it if required. I have got it working for almost all langauges (Korean, chinese, turky etc) except for Thai.

Thai is having some problem rendering in the silverlight grid (or any other control in silverlight). It shows only sqauare characters which is of no use. I dont know why Thai is treated specially by silverlight. Let me know if anyone has found a solution to work around this limitation?

Thanks
Shreedhar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using unicode of some sort for this.

You need to use a font which includes Thai characters (I believe [Arial Unicode MS](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fonts.html#arialunicodems) does, for example). The square characters you're seeing are probably [subsitute characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).

Comment: Thanks Dominic, this solved my issue.

I added FontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" to my datagrid in xaml and like a magic Thai characters showed up (as well as other languages). 

Really appreciate your time and help.

Thanks
Shreedhar